# Rerun a function when user click on any li.eq(i)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loadbar which I want to reload whenever user clicks on my li which is increment from a loop here is the following function that will be reload on li.eq(i)
live code: http://saadee.bl.ee/hm/

```
function lifeStream(){
    var lftanchor = $(".filetree span.file");
    var mainDiv = $(".main");
    var loadBg = $(".loadBg");
    var loadBar = $(".loadBar");
    var boxHeight = $(".box1, .box2");

    loadBg.show();
    loadBar.animate({"width":"100%"},1500);
    loadBg.hide();
    boxHeight.show();
    boxHeight.delay(1500).animate({"height":"0%"},300);
    loadBar.animate({"width":"0%"},0);
}
```

Comment: You could [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/) a click event to a list element.

Comment: @jogesh_pi I want to load this loading bar whenerver user clicks from the left li. I have tried on('click',function()) but its not working for me. here is the code: saadee.bl.ee/hm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) like,

```
$(function(){
   $('li').on('click',function(){
      lifeStream();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply handle the click event for the li that matches Your condition.

Considering i is defined, You can do:

```
jQuery('li').eq(i).click(function() {
 lifeStream();
});
```

Comment: I have tried it but its not working for me. it just runs on initial li index but not work for other li

Comment: Do You add the other li dynamically ?
If Then, You may want to have a look on Rohan Kumar answer.